# Looking for rotation rule - 3D vectors

Tags: matrices

here is my problem... to visualize... you are standing at the origin 0,0,0 .. facing Z(forward) Y(up) X(left/right).. there are two points in space anywhere... the goal is for you to grab one point in one hand and the other point in the other hand. so basically move to a point in between the two points and rotate to grab both points with your hands aligning you perfectly in between.

the middle point is calculated from both vectors in space...

and if i calculate a lookat to one vector, you may rotate and align properly.... but if i calculate using the second vector, you wont align properly. (or it doesn't in my results at the moment)

my problem is i don't know how to determine which vector to use to get the good alignment each and every time... is there a rule to pick to correct point/vector and my lookat will work flawlessly?

Now, i am not really looking for the "math" part... but more the logical/rules part.

i have done alot of looking around but cant seem to find anything pertaining to this.

thanks in advance for assisting. I have never really posted here so apologize if I am being naive about how this forum works.

cheers

Comment: You mention wanting to be between two points. Then suddenly you start talking about "both vectors". Where did they come from? What do they have to do with how you rotate and "align"? And why is lookat involved in any of this? You seem to have made a lot of unstated assumptions or conclusions already.

Comment: 2 points xyz same as two vectors xyz just different jargon.  - its two points with xyz coordinates. isn't this the basis of doing the calculations to find angles from these values ? do the rotations and then move the object in line in between the two points - rotated ?  what assumptions am I making ? do you have any suggestions to solve it ? Isn't it obvious that i don't know the answer and looking for the rules and logic to solve it ? Isn't the visual description enough to maybe write the steps down on how to get the proper rotation ?

Comment: i am at the point where i have calculated the angles and picking one or the other works but the rotation CCW or CW applied correctly or incorrectly to either may align or may not. i have two angles calculated from both points versus the center point calculated.

Comment: If I'm holding one point in my left hand and another in my right hand, I'm looking in a direction perpendicular to the line between those points (or I have turned my head and who knows where I am looking). If I'm actually in *space* (like an astronaut) my feet could be pointing in any direction perpendicular to the line between the points. Unless both points have the same $y$ coordinate it is certain that my arms are not horizontal, so I'm tilted to one side or another. Note that lookat *never* tilts the camera to either side, so it's no good if the $y$ coordinates are different.

Comment: Your first paragraph does indeed give a picture that seems to rule out most orientations, though it still lets me spin around the line through the two points so it doesn't really specify any particular orientation. If "vectors" in the second paratraph just means coordinates of points then that makes sense too. The worrisome part is the next couple of paragraphs, which seem to contradict the picture in the first paragraph. But if those paragraphs are just guesses, and the first paragraph is really the question, a little more clarification may be enough for someone to figure out an answer.

Comment: ok - i agree that you can spin in any direction as you stated. but it's a separate calculation from aligning you to hold the two points. so - a more simple example. flat on XZ plane. changing the object to a flat fence post at origin facing down Z painted white on the front and black on the back.... the fence post is to be duplicated along  the edge of the yard. same situation.. so the fence post needs to align in between each two points. - the yard like any yard is a shape and points are all around the yard....

Comment: now when i duplicate that post - it must be rotated along the edge of the yard and facing the good direction.... so all white sides one way and all black sides facing the other way..  so the normal of the plane avoids the "spinning" as you stated.  The issue here is that when I align the post and it happens to pick the angle and rotate it to be align. i can sometimes have a flip occurring. (separate issue but explaining)  - but my first concern is really getting the angle rules right... so in the fence example. the side of yard will eventually do a turn to the front of the yard.

Comment: so the points along the yard are now oriented differently, right.... and the angles versus the original position are changed. and now i need to again figure out CCW or CW so those rules have changed i guess? not sure ? - so this example there is no spinning but it's straight up from the ground the Y(up)  rotation is the "issue". hope this clarifies and thanks for assisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer I consider a more specific example offered in the comments.
Namely, the points are vertices of a polygon in the $x,z$ plane,
and it is assumed that the only rotation you will perform is a rotation around the $y$ axis, that is, whichever direction was "straight up" relative to your body will remain "straight up" relative to your body.

Let's list the vertices in sequence around the perimeter of the polygon,
starting with an arbitrary vertex and stopping when we return to that vertex.
That is, if there are $n$ vertices we can list them like this:
$P_0,P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_{n-1},P_0.$
For convenience, let $P_n$ be another name for $P_0.$
And let the coordinates of $P_k$ be $(x_k,0,z_k)$ for $0 \leq k \leq n.$

Let's also assume the polygon is a simple polygon, that is, it does not cross over itself. This way there is a clearly defined interior of the polygon
and a clearly defined exterior.

Now you can stand midway between two vertices, $P_k$ and $P_{k+1}$, and turn so that $P_k$ is directly to your left and $P_{k+1}$ is directly to your right.
You will be facing perpendicular to the edge of the polygon,
facing either the interior or exterior of the polygon.
If you follow this same procedure for $k=0,$ then $k=1,$ $k=2,$
etc. up to and including $k=n-1,$ you will visit each edge of the polygon.
Either you will be facing outward on every edge, or you will be facing inward on every edge.

So the orientations and locations you want are well defined.

Getting to the midpoint of a side is easy.
The coordinates of the midpoint of the edge from $P_k$ to $P_{k+1}$ are
$$ \left(\frac{x_k + x_{k+1}}2, 0, \frac{z_k + z_{k+1}}2\right).$$
You should be able to obtain a translation matrix $T$ that moves you from the origin to those coordinates.

To define the orientations in a mathematical way, we can use the direction of each side.

The vector from $P_k$ to $P_{k+1}$ is $(x_{k+1} - x_k, 0, z_{k+1} - z_k).$
This vector points in the same direction as the direction from
the origin to the point $(x_{k+1} - x_k, 0, z_{k+1} - z_k).$
So one way to get a matrix to orient you in that direction might be a lookat function if you have one where you can (in effect) put the camera at the origin and turn the camera to face the point $(x_{k+1} - x_k, 0, z_{k+1} - z_k).$

Another option is to find the angle that the vector
$(x_{k+1} - x_k, 0, z_{k+1} - z_k)$ makes with the positive $z$ axis in the $x,z$ plane, looking down from the positive $y$ axis.
The angle is $\operatorname{atan2}(x_{k+1} - x_k, z_{k+1} - z_k)$ radians counterclockwise.
So the rotation matrix to turn you from facing the positive $z$ direction to facing the direction $(x_{k+1} - x_k, 0, z_{k+1} - z_k)$
is the standard matrix for a rotation of
$\operatorname{atan2}(x_{k+1} - x_k, z_{k+1} - z_k)$ radians around the $y$ axis.

Assuming your transformation matrices are for transformations of world coordinates of your body, you would first apply the rotation matrix and then the translation matrix.
Alternatively, in terms of matrix multiplication, if the rotation matrix is $R$ and the translation matrix is $T$ you want the matrix $TR$ (first transformation goes on the right).

This procedure has one flaw: it leaves you facing *along* the edge of the polygon rather than perpendicular to it.
You need an extra $90$ degrees ($\frac\pi2$ radians) of rotation to face perpendicular to the edge. So just apply that rotation first.
If $R_{\pi/2}$ is the matrix to rotate $90$ degrees around the $y$ axis,
then the complete transformation is $T R R_{\pi/2}.$

This procedure should have you facing inward from the midpoint of each edge of the polygon, or outward from the midpoint of each edge of the polygon.
It depends on whether you originally listed the vertices of the polygon in counterclockwise sequence or clockwise sequence.

To consider how you might decide which way is which:

If you know how to measure the signed angle between two vectors in the $x,z$ plane -- that is, you can measure the angle so that a positive angle is a left turn and a negative angle is a right turn -- then add up all the angles as you go around the polygon once (so you add $n$ angles).
The sum should be either $2\pi$ radians or $-2\pi$ radians (approximately, allowing for roundoffs during the calculation).
If it's $2\pi$ radians you are going counterclockwise and the exterior of the polygon is on the right; in the other case the exterior is on the left.

Another method is to choose a number $C$ between the $z$ coordinates of vertices, not equal to the $z$ coordinate of any vertex. (You can just list all the $z$ coordinates in ascending order, choose a pair of $z$ values, and set $C$ halfway between them.)

Now consider the line $z = C.$ Your polygon must cross that line at least twice, or possibly more times (as in the example below).

[image]

Each crossing crosses the line $z = C$ at a different $x$ value.
Find the maximum $x$ value among all the crossings, and consider the edge that crosses at this $x$ value.
In the example, this edge is the one from $P_3$ to $P_4.$
We see in this example that the $z$ coordinate increases as you go from $P_3$ to $P_4,$ which means the exterior of the polygon is on the left.
If the $z$ coordinate had decreased, the exterior of the polygon is on the right.

These particular rules make a number of assumptions about the coordinate system. If one of these assumptions is wrong -- for example, the coordinate system is left-handed instead of right-handed, or the $y$ axis points downward instead of upward, or the sense or the rotation matrix is left-handed instead of right-handed -- then the procedure could say to turn the wrong way. But if it does so, it will be wrong every single time, so you just need to do the opposite and then it will always work.

Comment: hi David, thank you for taking the time to write this excellent explanation.... all good however the very last sentence you stated is probably the reason why i don't align.... how do i determine that ? the CCW and/or CW of the points... for example, I can manually select two points...but what says picking one first and the other second makes it ccw or not and that one point will be the  Zk+1 or  Zk (as you stated)...it's either/or right ?  if I pick in order one way or in order the other way... the rotation result will be for example either -45 or 135 on Y?

Comment: so which angle value to use at that specific midpoint. I see some examples on this forum where it tells you to draw a line through the polygon and depending on how many borders I cross - it will be my answer but i don't think that really applies here... unless i misunderstood something in your explanation and BIG thanks once again... can you please clarify that very last sentence ? I believe that is really the rule I may be looking for

Comment: hey David, i reworded my search and found this...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315401/explanation-of-ccw-algorithm

Comment: a quick test showing promising results....

Comment: unfortunately it fails depending on positions of the k+1,k.... ie depending on the quadrant in falls in.... i have bee trying to figure this out for weeks now !!! lol

Comment: Hey David, yup this solves it.... i came here because i was exhausted from searching so much !!!  i owe you !!!  with the signed angle approach it works.... now i have to rest my head for a couple of days !!!! omg one simple added calculation does the job !!!  amazing !!!!

Comment: now i need to figure out how to give you the credit ? not sure how to do that on this site.

Comment: I'm glad it helped!